# HTML/CSS: Put content in a footer with background image?

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a wrapper with header, body(content) and a footer, so a typical structure.

Header is done, body is done, now I am trying to make the footer, but I dont know how to do it the way i want.

For the footer I have a background-image and "in" the image I want more content to put in (like some links, buttons, etc. for example), but I just can't find a solution for it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class=footer-background">
            <img class="..."..... alt "Image">
        </div>
        <div class=footer-content">
            //Links, Buttons and other things
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The footer-content part is done and looks how I wanted, now my question would be, how I put the content above the background image of the footer?
Is the  placement there right or do I have to solve this in a completely different way?

I tried it already with:

```
footer-background {
...
top: -100px;
...
}

footer-content {
...
top: -250px;
...
}
```

With that I kinda have what I want, but then I have a white space underneath the footer and that must not be there in any case. Probably I am too stupid and the solution is easy, but I am thankful for every help I get!

Comment: Why don't you just set the background image in CSS?

Comment: I tried that already with:

    background-image: url("footer.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;

But somehow it doesnt show the whole picture (the height of it)..

Comment: Well `background-size: cover` literally means "resize so that it fills the entire height and width and cut the part that doesn't fit." If you don't want that then remove that rule

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.footer {
   background-image: url('https://www.tutorialkart.com/sample_image.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-background">
            <p>Links, Buttons and other things</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try inserting the image from css using background-image: url(then insert your jpg url here) and changing background size to 'contain?

```
.footer-background {
        background-image: url(https://images.wherever.com/...);
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

If you do this, you can add your links in the HTML without having to work tamper with margins.
Try it and let's knwo if it's a fix